# Could not open input file composer.phar in Windows 7

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I am trying to install an extension in Yii2, while I installing through command prompt using

```
C:\wamp\www\project>php composer.phar require mdmsoft/yii2-admin "~1.0"
```

I am getting an error like this:

> could not open input file composer.phar

Comment: Did the answers below help at all, Kalai?

Comment: @Fory has mentioned the perfect answer below, first you need to set path for composer.phar with prefix php tag followed by the required install command (may be update or new install)

Answer (score 11):

Where did you install composer?

You have to add the directory, for example:

```
php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar require ...
```

If you add the directory to your windows path you can simply call

```
composer require ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Read here https://getcomposer.org/download/ it gives you instructions for how to get composer.

The easier way is to run

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

In that directory.

Or you can follow these instructions https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows so you can reuse it for other projects too.

Answer (score 2):

Type `composer require mdmsoft/yii2-admin "~1.0"` in your cmd

Answer (score 2):

in windows execute

```
composer require mdmsoft/yii2-admin "~1.0"
```

regards!